# Can I get a Wage and Income Transcript if I've never filed a tax return?

Tags: united-states, irs

I have never filed a tax return because I have never made enough money to be required to do so. I was just wondering if the IRS would still have a wage and income transcript for me even though I have never filed a tax return, because I still made money.

Comment: **In addition** to the 10 years available from IRS, for money from _employment_ only, **Social Security** keeps an earnings record for your whole life, and will gladly give you a copy accompanied by some <strike>ads</strike> helpful info about how great SS benefits will be when you retire. (Until 2009 they sent this 'statement' by mail every year automatically, at least if they had your correct address -- they had mine from when I got a replacement card.)

Answer (score 6):

From the [IRS web site](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/tax-return-transcript-types-and-ways-to-order-them):

> - **Wage and Income Transcript** - shows data from information returns we receive such as Forms W-2, 1099, 1098 and Form 5498, IRA Contribution Information.

So if your income was reported to the IRS (by the payer, not you) using one of the forms above, the IRS would have a record of it, regardless of whether you filed a tax return or not.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the jobs where you've earned money from have sent you W-2s, 1099s, etc. Then yes, you can request a [Wage and Income Transcript](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/tax-return-transcript-types-and-ways-to-order-them):

> Shows data from information returns we receive such as Forms W-2,
>   1099, 1098 and Form 5498, IRA Contribution Information. Current tax
>   year information may not be complete until July. This transcript is
>   available for up to 10 prior years using Get Transcript Online or Form
>   4506-T.